# Fast way to insert nested JSON to Hadoop (Spark Java)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I need to write to Hadoop around 150B nested Json records per day (Using Spark Java),

What is the "fast" way to do it in term of performance for example :

1. Create Hive table and write parquet file to HDFS
2. Or create `Dataset` from Json and using `saveAsTable`

Or is there another way of doing it ?

Comment: What exactly is the difference in those options? Spark can create a Parquet Hive table itself... If you just want data in HDFS, why do you need Hive or Parquet?

Comment: @cricket_007, Actually I just want to know what will be the best option for me in term of performance

Comment: ORC and Parquet obviously are better than JSON. Whether you use Spark or Hive to get the data in that format doesn't really matter, I would think